# 'Error: Could not find or load main class" after adding JAR dependency

Tags: java, javafx, jar, jgit

After I added JGit (the jar) dependency in intelliJ, my app wouldn't open (when launching the app from the output .jar file) and the console gives me an error saying "Error: Could not find or load main class kyr.reciter.ReciterProgram"

But when I run the app from intelliJ everything works fine.

Before adding JGit, my program ran fine on both the intelliJ console and executable jar file.

Full log after adding dependency:

```
C:\Users\Abdelrahman\Desktop\Reciter Program\processor>java -jar NewReciterProgram.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class kyr.reciter.ReciterProgram

C:\Users\Abdelrahman\Desktop\Reciter Program\processor>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have looked for hours through countless forum pages and haven't found a solution yet.

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance. Please let me know if I need to post more info.

Comment: Do you have the main class? I jar file should be a single object program which you usually use the main class to run. Although it is not necessary. Maybe you need to deploy before making jar file cause class file need to update sometimes.

Comment: There should be more than just the single line in the error. The rest of the stacktrace should provide info about the exact problem with the main class.

Comment: @fabian The error is only one line and there is no stack trace, and the program immediately shuts down afterwards. The jar file worked perfectly before I added the dependency.

Comment: Have you checked the results of `jar tf NewReciterProgram.jar` for the class file for the main class and the dependencies especially the JGit stuff used in the main class? (unless those sources are in the working directory or `jre/lib/ext`...)

Comment: @fabian I really appreciate you following up with this. When I ran `jar tf NewReciterProgram.jar` it gave me the following `C:\Users\Abdelrahman\Desktop\Reciter Program\processor>java tf NewReciterProgram.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class tf` I have made a launcher class that launches the application, but nothing changed.